# Accessing "private" variable behind python property

Tags: python, properties, scope

How do you access the "private" variable behind a Python property?

In the following code, I get `Hello World` instead of the `World World` that I expect. I would guess that the property has a different scope that results in `self` being different in the property than the module. If so, is there a way to access the underlying variable? Or is there a different idiom to use for "code outside the class should use a different getter than code in the class"?

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 'Hello'
        self.x = 'World'

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self._x = val

foo = Foo()
print(foo._x)
print(foo.x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* accessing the private variable `_x` via `foo._x`.

What is typical in this situation is to not define the `x` attribute at all, i.e. remove the line `self.x = 'World'`. That way you are using the *property* `x` to access the *attribute* `_x` (and because privates aren't really private you can of course also access the attribute directly using `_x`).

**Edit:** the first part of my answer was misleading, see user2357112's answer for why you are not getting the expected output.

Comment: @QtotheC see my edit, my original answer was misleading.

Comment: There is also a difference between *protected* and *private*. Protected attributes have a single underscore and they are protected by convention (e.g. signal for other programmers not to use it outside of (sub)class). If you need a stronger protection, you can use double underscores. This is the best you can do in Python. But it's not really private as in other programming languages. It may help in OOP, not finding a way into the subclass, for example.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to inherit from `object`, so you created an old-style class. `property` setters don't work for old-style classes. If you inherit from `object`, you get `World` from both `print`s, like you expected:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._x = 'Hello'
...         self.x = 'World'
...     @property
...     def x(self):
...         return self._x
...     @x.setter
...     def x(self, val):
...         self._x = val
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> print foo._x
World
>>> print foo.x
World
```

Comment: Inferring from the `print` vs. `print()`, you are using python2, and it looks like the OP uses python3; if this is the case, your "old style" classes explanation doesn't hold.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: But on Python 3, [they would have gotten `World` both times](http://ideone.com/gDSsex). I think it's more likely that the questioner is using `print` with parentheses because they simply aren't very aware of Python version differences and conventional syntax.